# Stylesheet path for fancybox is not correct in Wordpress NextGEN gallery plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, fancybox, nextgen-gallery

I have created the demo wordpress site under a subdomain of my main domain `www.abcdef.com`. And I installed NextGEN gallery plugin for displaying gallery. Everything worked fine and I thought about moving the site to it's own domain. Changed the site URLs and other things and moved the whole files to the new location. Everything works fine now, except the fancybox module where it is supposed to open up the picture in a popup box when clicked!

Upon my investigation, I found that the path of stylesheet for Fancybox is still pointing to my old subdomain's! But all other stlyesheets and javascript files are included with the correct path(ie. it is showing with respect to the new domain). Only this fancybox's stylesheet is showing wrong.

Tried to manually check the database's `wp-options` table for any entry mentioning my old subdomain, but didn't found anything. Double checked by executing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_value` LIKE '%mysite.abcdef.com%'
```

Didn't found anything! To make sure that it isn't a cache issue, I tried removing the cache too. Didn't worked either!

Then tried to manually inspect each PHP page belonging to that plugin. But I couldn't find anywhere mentioning my old subdomain in paths!

I'm really confused now! Currently it is showing like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox-0-css'  href='http://mysite.abcdef.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?ver=3.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nextgen_basic_album_style-css'  href='http://mynewdomain.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_album/static/nextgen_basic_album.css?ver=3.6' type='text/css' media='all' />

<!-- ........... rest of the things shown with href value starting with "http://mynewdomain.com" ........... -->
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolved the problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

you want to do only one thing go to NextGen Gallery. From your WordPress dashboard, go to Gallery -> Other Options -> Lightbox Effects -> (Show Advanced Settings)
and you can see url for fancy box changed all url according to you site url.
that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably .htaccess related. Temporarily disable any RewriteRule rules by commenting out with # and reload the problematic page.